# Django Aggregation: Aggregate on relational queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Suppose I have following models, which store questions and options for those questions.

P.S: I am just writing the basic code just to give you idea.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField()

class Option(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField()

class QuestionOption(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    option = models.ForeignKey(Option)
```

And then I have models which store user Feedback and Options selected for each Question in the Feedback survey.

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField()
    cell_phone = models.CharField()
    created_at = models.DateTime()

class FeedbackOption(models.Model):
    feedback = models.ForeignKey(Feedback, related_name='feedback_options')
    option = models.ForeignKey(QuestionOption)
```

Every feedback will have lots of feedback option objects. Now I want to filter all the feedback whose feedback options contain specific QuestionOption object and then perform aggregate query where I am checking if that feedback's FeedbackOptions option text is 'boo' add count. Can i do this in one step, Something like this

```
# lets say i want to filter all feedback with QuestionOption id 1
stats = Feedback.objects.filter(feedback_options__option=1).aggregate(
    boo=Count(Case(When(feedback_options__option__option__text='boo', then=1))),
    hoo=Count(Case(When(feedback_options__option__option__text='hoo', then=1))))
```

It looks like it's applying aggregate on the only feedback option where option id is 1 not the rest of the feedback options for each feedback.

Comment: You want a count *per* text, or only for `'boo'`, and `'hoo'`?

Comment: I want to check all the feedback options for the feedback which contain a feedback option with id 1, and count all the feedback options where text is 'boo' and 'hoo'

Comment: Right now I've achieved this by doing this in two different parts. 
First, I filter all the feedback and make a `values_list('id', flat=True)`
Second, using the list of feedback I filter all the feedback options `FeedbackOption.objects.filter(feedback__in=feedback_list)` and apply the aggregate query.

Comment: Do you require multiple counts like `boo=4` and `hoo=5` or `boo_and_hoo=9`? As asked by @WillemVanOnsem do you only want count for `boo` and `hoo` or a group by on all the texts?

Comment: I want boo=4 and hoo=5.

Answer (score 0):

`.filter()` works as a where clause. When you add another method like `.aggregate()`to the resulting queryset, it is bounded by the same where clause.

In Django 1.11 you can use `Subquery`

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Count

Feedback.objects.filter(feedback_options__option=o1).annotate(
    boo=Subquery(
        FeedbackOption.objects.filter(option__option__text="boo", feedback=OuterRef('pk')).values('feedback').annotate(count=Count('pk')).values('count'), 
        output_field=models.IntegerField())
    )
```

Similarly you can add another annotation for `hoo`.

[Doc reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)